# SignalR Updating TextArea realtime

Tags: html, asp.net, signalr, real-time

Hi i just started learning SignalR v2. I have a textarea in my aspx page and i want to update it in realtime whenever a user presses a key on it.

**Issue:** I opened 2 tabs in my browser.
If i type the first character example **"a"**, nothing happens:
Tab1 textarea: "a"
tab2 textarea: NOTHING

Then i proceed to type the second character **"b"**
Tab1 textarea: "ab"
tab2 textarea: "a"

**Conclude:** Its always not updating the latest character i typed!

**SignalR Class**

```
 public class DocHub : Hub
    {
       public void Update(String text)
       {
           this.Clients.Others.updateText(text);
       }
    }
```

**index.aspx**

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="font-size:50px;"> New Document</div>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="ta"></textarea>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js"></script>
    <script src="signalr/hubs"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var hubProxy = $.connection.docHub;
            hubProxy.client.updateText = function (msg) {
                $("#ta").val(msg);
            };
            $("#ta").keydown(function () {
                hubProxy.server.update($("#ta").val());
            });

            $.connection.hub.start();

        });
    </script>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really would try to use keyup instead