# signalR update textarea in realtime

Tags: c#, signalr

how to make a textarea update all the other clients textarea as well and vise versa in signalR. if i update a textarea the textarea on second tab automatically update. without clicking a button.

Comment: did you do any research on your own ...?

Comment: Did any of the answers help you or should I remove my answer?

Comment: the example i referred below helped me. and its working

Answer (score 0):

You need to communicate to the SignalR hub and then the hub will need to broadcast an event that indicates the data has changed to all connected clients in all tabs/browsers.

You will need to initiate the communication to the hub on the textbox's onChange event, e.g. `$(...).change(function() {notifyChange()})` or `ng-change="notifyChange()"`

The event handler for the broadcasted signalR event will then need to read the event message body and apply `$(...).val(msgText)`

Comment: kindly share some example. because i am new in signalR

Comment: first i am following this example [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30326904/signalr-updating-textarea-realtime/30327189#30327189)

Comment: The example you have linked is correct. If your hub is not working, can you please make sure when you call hubProxy.server.update($("#ta").val());
the server breakpoint on Update() is reached?
If not, i can see a few places it might fail. it might be a problem establishing connection with the hub. or even your html change event handler is not registered properly.
Or can you put a console log on your html element change handler to make sure the hub.server function is invoked?

Comment: I don't see any references to AngularJS in the question

Comment: @MarkC.just trying to help as much as possible, how do you know there is no usage of angular in the question poster's code?.